# How to consume https soap webservice inside Spring MVC @controller

Tags: java, spring

The user case is as below:
browser client <==> spring mvc (axis1 client) <==> https soap webservice

When I apply the same codes from standalone into spring MVC @controller, it is getting stuck during locating remote webservice port process.

```
WebServiceLocator locator = new WebServiceLocator(); 
locator.setWebPortEndpointAddress(webserviceURL);  
WebServicePort port= locator.getWebServicePort(); 
//getting stuck here
```

Any help is appreciated.